# How do I apply a VBA Word script to the entire document?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have no experience with VBA scripting whatsoever, but with the help of the posts I found, I was able to find what I was looking for and make it work for the most part. See the code I'm using below.

I have a Word document template that will become a senior leadership report. The leadership team is insisting on coloring the categories: low, medium, high, and critical, so I'm trying to color the word accordingly; green, yellow, darkred, and red. It does work on some pages of my report but it completely skips other sections. For example, it will change the font color of Low on the second page but not on the first page. On the first page, the word Low is in a table and in a text box.

How to I get this script to work throughout the entire document?

```vb
Sub AutoOpen()

ActiveDocument.Content.Font.Color = vbBlack

ColorText ActiveDocument.Content, "breaks", vbRed
ColorText ActiveDocument.Content, "it", vbBlue
ColorText ActiveDocument.Content, "with just", vbGreen

End Sub


Sub ColorText(rng As Range, strFind As String, clr As Long)
With rng.Find
    .Text = strFind
    .Forward = True
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = True
    Do While .Execute()
        rng.Font.Color = clr 'rng is redefined as the found text
    Loop
End With
End Sub
```

I tried variations of this script but haven't been able to make it work.